# Where clause on view using sub query with temp table taking exceptionally long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, sql-view

When I use a select * from view where column in (xxxx) and use sub query which is a simple list of id's it is taking almost 1000 times longer to execute than to simply enter the list of numbers, example below.

A) takes 0ms to execute

```
SELECT Name FROM TMS.dbo.vPerson p WHERE p.personid IN (1,2,3,4)
```

B) takes 3200ms to execute

```
SELECT personid INTO #persons FROM  tcPerson p WHERE p.personid IN (1,2,3,4)
SELECT Name FROM TMS.dbo.vPerson p 
WHERE p.personid IN (SELECT personid FROM #persons)
```

I have made sure to clear cache each time, but there seems to be no valid reason why this takes so much longer.

the temp table is quite literally just a list of 4 ids. the creation of it can be ignored, and the selection of the values in the where query is negligible

All help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Little confused, A does 1 query, B does 5 ... (your last statement has 3 queries within the whole)

Comment: true, there are 4 select's however, selecting the personid seperatly only takes 1ms at most, this would leave another 3000ish seconds to account for.

Comment: OK but some linq isnt actually performed at the line you write it on.. so the A may not actually have processed the linq yet. you would need to access it.  Put in a stopwatch line, and find which of your queries takes the time, because A is nothing like  B... the first line of B sure.. but its still on a different end container.. one could be local memory another a long distance remote heavy loaded sql server with no indexes..

Comment: this is inside of a stored procedure, linq isn't being used.  However to elaborate more on the temp table, the creation of it can be ignored, and the selection of the values in the where query is negligble

Comment: Good point on linq - I thought it said c# on the list - ok.. so, whats the difference between vPerson and tcPerson? as tcPerson only exists in B

Comment: How many persons are there in the main table (`tcPerson`?) and is there an index on `personid`? How is the VIEW?

Comment: Table definitions (including indexes) along with query plans are generally necessary to help with performance tuning.

Comment: these are all valid points, the table is around 1 million in size, the execution plans are identical for both. And there are indexes on personid however as i am using sql 2008 indexes can not be added to the view ( I am not using the enterprise edition)

Comment: lack of index would explain the speed difference for sure

Comment: But I am uncertain as to why using a select on a temp table to retrieve 4 values, is causing it to take much longer than simply entering those four values?

Comment: What if you use EXISTS instead on IN

Comment: 1. Try exists instead of `IN`; 2. Compare _actual_ query plans (include actual plan) between the temp table and explicit value queries and compare the actual and estimated row counts

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM TMS.dbo.vPerson p 
WHERE p.personid IN (SELECT personid
                     FROM TMS.dbo.tcPerson p
                     WHERE p.personid IN (SELECT personid FROM #persons)
                    )
```

Sometimes, `IN` is harder to optimize than other versions of a query.  You can tell by looking at the execution plan.  I do note that this query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT Name
FROM TMS.dbo.vPerson p 
WHERE p.personid IN (SELECT personid FROM TMS.dbo.tcPerson p) AND
      p.person_id IN (SELECT personid FROM #persons)
```

The nested subqueries are unnecessary.  This query should be fine if you have indexes on `tcPerson(personid)` and `#persons(personid)`.

Comment: the actual temp table is derived from a much larger query which results in just for values being returned. If I take those 4 values and run seperatly I get the equivalent of the above, however is still a valid point

Comment: On re reading I have noticed you are correct that I did not need the sub query select id's and have updated accordingly, However the issue is still present that selecting from the temp table to provide a a list of 4 ids to the view's where clause is taking much loinger